# My application opens on tablets but said to be unsuitable for tablets

Tags: android, screen-orientation

i have written the codes I needed in my androidmanifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

I also have dimens files with different screen sizes.

1. values-w320dp-hdpi-480x800
2. values-w320dp-hdpi-480x854
3. values-w320dp-ldpi-240x400
4. values-w320dp-ldpi-240x432
5. values-w320dp-mdpi-320x480
6. values-w360dp-hdpi-720x1280
7. values-w360dp-xhdpi-720x1280
8. values-w360dp-xxhdpi-1080x1920
9. values-w411dp-xxhdpi-1080x1920
10. values-w411dp-xxxhdpi-1440x2560
11. values-w411dp-xxxhdpi-1440x2880
12. values-w480dp-mdpi-480x800
13. values-w480dp-mdpi-480x854
14. values-w533dp-hdpi-800x1280
15. values-w600dp-hdpi-800x1280
16. values-w600dp-mdpi-600x1024
17. values-w600dp-xhdpi-1200x1920
18. values-w768dp-xhdpi-2048x1536
19. values-w768dp-xhdpi-2560x1800
20. values-w800dp-mdpi-800x1280
21. values-w800dp-xhdpi-2560x1600

I can't understand why it works correctly on the tablets. Do I also need to write a code?

Comment: WHy wouldn't it work on tablets?  And why do you have so many dimen files?  if you have more than 3 or so, you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why it's bad that there are more than 3 dimens? I have a lot of dimens file because I want it to be shown on different devices. I made these files according to device metrics.

Comment: Because they aren't needed, and make your app extremely fragile and difficult to modify.  If you need more than 3 or so dimens files AT MOST, you didn't understand how to design your app properly in the first place.  Most apps need 0 and still scale perfectly.

Comment: But How do I ? @GabeSechan , said "This app may not be optimized for your device"

Comment: To have fewer dimens files, should I take into account the general dimensions? (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc...)

Comment: Without knowing everything about your UI code I can't tell you that.  But that error message has nothing to do with dimens files.  It just means you don't have 7 and 10 inch screenshots in your store listing

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan, It actually has a 7 inch screenshot but does it have to be 10 inches? Should I also put?